# static member variable in a class function with multithreading deleted by another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

I have a static member variable in a class:

```
template <class T>
class classFactory
{
...
public:
...
    typedef std::map<KeyType, Creatory>  Creator;
...
private:
...
    static Creator &GetCreators()
    {
       static Creator creator;
       return creator;
    }
}
```

An exit()->atexit() was called on the main() function which called a global destructor and deleted this static member creator.

another thread was still accessing this static member using the same GetCreators() function and caused a crash.

My question:

1. Where is this static member allocated? I know it is an uninitialized global so it should go on BSS? But why does it get destroyed by the global destructor even when it is in the static member function?
2. I was told making it a new would fix this problem -> global destructor will leave it out.

i.e.

```
static Creator &GetCreators()
    {
        static Creator* creator = new Creator;
        return *creator;
    }
```

Why would this fix the problem? Because now it goes on the heap? Why would the global destructor leave this alone?
In this case, when should I delete this object. I have no way of knowing which thread will be last in execution.

Now I did try making the object a thread_local but this makes many of my programs crash (this is a driver framework called by other clients).

```
static Creators &GetCreators()
{
    thread_local static Creators creators;

    return creators;
}
```

The reason , I think , is that the object creation becomes timing based when I make it thread_local static and causes many race conditions.

Comment: The 'global destructor' does not touch the heap. And you don't normally delete a heap allocated singleton, so this method is not appropriate if the destructor of `Creator` has important work to do, But if that's not the case then this seems to be the solution for you.

Comment: @John, Destructor of Creator has nothing to destroy. No important work being done in the destructor. Then it is ok? So basically the answer is that the global destructor will not touch the static member variable because it is on heap and not BSS?

Comment: Not quite, the variable is `creators` and that is in BSS. But pointers don't have destructors and also the object it is pointing to is on the heap.

Comment: Incidentally, BSS is not a concept that really exists in C++. I used the term because you did, but really it is specific to certain compilers on certain platforms.

Comment: So if it was not BSS, it was on global stack? Stored as global variable on global stack because it was static member of the class? Also does it matter if static member is in the static function or outside the static function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by global stack. Although there C++ standard does not use these terms basically there is global memory, stack memory and heap memory. `creator` is not a static member, it's a static local variable. But static local variables, static member variables and global variables all reside in global memory, but there are different rules for *visibility* and *lifetime*.

Comment: Static local variables are constructed/initialised the first time the containing function is called. Static member and global variables are constructed/initialised before `main` is called.

Comment: You are correct. My bad. It is basically a part of the Data Segment. Namely, the uninitialized data segment. So originally static creator was going on the uninitialized data segment.  

With the fix, the class has a pointer which is a class global variable itself but the memory it pointed to is now on the heap memory (allocated with new). Pointers don't have destructors so it will not get destroyed. So this static pointer will live on for that class.

Comment: Yep, that's right. But careful with the word deleted, but that suggests that the global destructor calls `delete` on the pointer and that is **not** the case. As I said earlier pointers do not have destructors, so the global destructor does nothing with the pointer.

Comment: Re, "...global stack..."  "Global" is a _scope._ The scope of a variable is the set of locations within the program text from which the variable is accessible. Variables in the global scope are accessible from every part of the program. Your `creator` variable has _local_ scope. It cannot be accessed from anyplace outside the body of the `GetCreators()` function. At the same time though, the _extent_ of `creator` (i.e., how long it keeps its value) is the whole lifetime of the process because it is declared to be `static`.

Comment: Instead of saying "global stack," maybe say, "the main thread's stack" instead. You tagged your question with [tag:multithreading]. Each thread in a multi-threaded process must have its own separate stack. But "stack" really is not even part of the language: It's just an implementation detail.